# Java Stream API - Merge objects in collection if two fields are the same

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Member:

```
public class Member {
 private Integer id; 
 private Integer age; 
 private Double amount; 
}
```

And what I want to do is transform the following input into output:

```
Input : 
[id =10, age =20, amount= 100.00]
[id =10, age =20, amount= 200.00]
[id =11, age =22, amount= 100.00]
[id =11, age =22, amount= 100.00]
[id =12, age =20, amount= 100.00]
Output :
[id =10, age =20, amount= 300.00]
[id =11, age =22, amount= 200.00]
[id =12, age =20, amount= 100.00]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, group `List<Member>` by `id` and `age` then sum `Member` which is in the same group.

```
Member member = new Member(10, 20, 100.00);
Member member1 = new Member(10, 20, 200.00);
Member member2 = new Member(11, 22, 100.00);
Member member3 = new Member(11, 22, 100.00);
Member member4 = new Member(12, 20, 100.00);
        
List<Member> members = Stream.of(member, member1, member2, member3, member4).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>, List<Member>> mapMembers = members.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i.getId(), i.getAge())));
        
Map<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>, Member> map = mapMembers.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        u -> new Member(
                                u.getKey().getKey(),
                                u.getKey().getValue(),
                                u.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(Member::getAmount)
                                        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                        .sum()
                        )
                ));
        
System.out.println(map.values());
```

Comment: 1) The `amount` type field is not the same as the one in your question (`BigDecimal` is much better to store amounts like this than using doubles). 2) I guess the `map` return type is not what you'd really need and can be replaced with `List<Member>` (the return map key entry type is the same as its value type fields). 3) You don't need to stream-stream-stream (for the 1st pass, then 2nd pass, then the `sum` pass just because it has such a method), but you can implement a specialized collector that could aggregate the entire stream in one pass.

Comment: 4) Additionally, your collectors (the grouping and the final one) are based on hash-maps therefore it would provide you results in "undefined" order, not necessarily the same as you're expecting in your question.

Comment: You create a `Stream` which you convert to a `List`. Then you create a `Stream` from the `List`. Why do you need to convert to a `List` and then back to a `Stream`? Can't you simply use the initial `Stream` that you created?

Comment: @Abra: I just want to solve the closed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120713/add-the-elements-in-list-using-stream). Maybe it is not an optimal solution.

Comment: @logbasex I meant, it would be better to keep `BigDecimal` and change your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Member {
    private int id; 
    private int age; 
    private double amount;

    public Member(int id, int age, double amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String display() {
        return String.format("%d %d", id, age);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = this == obj;
        if (!equal) {
            if (obj != null) {
                if (getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
                    Member other = (Member) obj;
                    equal = id == other.id  &&  age == other.age;
                }
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return display().hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %d %.2f", id, age, amount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(new Member(10, 20, 100.00),
                  new Member(10, 20, 200.00),
                  new Member(11, 22, 100.00),
                  new Member(11, 22, 100.00),
                  new Member(12, 20, 100.00))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                             Collectors.reducing(0.0d,
                                                                 m -> m.getAmount(),
                                                                 (sum, amt) -> sum += amt)))
              .forEach((key, val) -> System.out.printf("%s %s%n", key.display(), val));
    }
}
```

I completed class `Member` by adding a constructor and other methods that are required in order to achieve your desired result.

In method `main`, the `groupingBy` is used to generate a `Map` where the [map] key is an instance of class `Member`. It calls [overridden] method [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--), in class `Member`, in order to check for equal keys.

It is recommended to also override method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) in a class that overrides method `hashCode`.

Without the `reducing` method, the `Map` value would be a list of all `Member` instances with the same `id` and `age`. The `reducing` method sums the `amount` from each `Member` in a single list.

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
12 20 100
10 20 300
11 22 200
```